# Scala higher order function that filters even numbers

Tags: scala

I am relatively new to Scala and have been going through some tutorials on the web. I am currently learning higher-order functions and have come across this example:

```
val filter = (predicate: Int => Boolean, xs: List[Int]) => {
  for (x <- xs if predicate(x)) yield x
}
```

The function filters even values from a list.. but I cannot figure out which parameters the function call takes.

I also have another questions:

- Can someone explain what the: `predicate: Int => Boolean` parameter is doing?
- And what if I did this: `predicate: Int => Boolean => Boolean`?

I am a little confused to how that chaining pattern works...

Comment: the `predicate` does what it says - it is uesed to check which elements of the list should be yielded (only those elements `x` where `predicate(x)` is true)

Comment: the function takes two parameters: another function `predicate` (that's why `filter` is called higher-order) and a integer-list `xs`

Comment: If you change the `predicate` argument then the question is **why**? - What shall the second input be? I cannot answer this - it's like this question: "If I dream of pink elephants will those elephants be flying?"

Comment: I think Geem7n is asking about the meaning of the `=>` notation in the type signature; i.e. "What would a hypothetical type signature of `foo: Int => Boolean => Boolean` mean"? (it would be a function that takes an `Int` and returns a function from `Boolean` to `Boolean`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that function doesn't filter even values from a list. It is a more general function that performs filtering according to a predicate function that you pass to it. The signature

```
val filter = (predicate : Int => Boolean, xs: List[Int]) => ...
```

tells you that `filter` is a function that takes as an argument two values:

- The argument `predicate` is itself a functin from `Int` to `Boolean`
- The argument `xs` is a `List` of `Int`s

you can pass in a function that checks whether a number is even as your predicate:

```
val isEven = (x: Int) => x % 2 == 0
filter(isEven, List(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers.. the reference to the code can be found here http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/high-higher-higher-order-functions/